# How to connect my two break and check screens through login button using if else statement in flutter

Tags: flutter

This is my Navigate screen. [This is my Navigate Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uwh1.png). In which there are two buttons of Break & check After this screen goes to login screen on which I have to make Condition that if I click on Break then after login Break screen should open & if I click on check then after login Check screen should be open.[This is my Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkE3a.png).
[This is my check screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFbXP.png) & [This is my Break screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlv7q.png).I hope you understand my problem & giving quick solution to this.

I am expecting to get specific screen on clicking the specific break or check button.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the next page as a parameter to the login screen.

So that on the onPressed of the break button you'll have:

```
onPressed() => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignInScreen(nextPage: 'break')));
```

and on that of the check button you can have:

```
onPressed() => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignInScreen(nextPage: 'check')));
```

Then you can have an if check within the SignInScreen and based on it move to the desired page